# Using Perl to send sms via Twilio

Tags: perl, twilio

I have an extensive app in Perl that sends an occasional txt msg to me, and me only.  Definitely not a spammer.  I've had this app running for years on Plivo, but recently they have cut me off via 10DLC campaigns.  I have not been able to convince them that this is extremely low volume and does not go to a wide-spread audience - it's actually sending notices from a weather station of particular events, like temp going below freezing, high wind, etc.

So I'm trying to change over to Twilio to see if that works out better for me.

I have tried using their sample windows command-line CURL example, and this does work, I am able to successfully send a msg.

As my program is in Perl, there's no pre-built API, so I'm having to manually craft the request packet myself.  My old Plivo code forms a tidy json packet, albeit with different names.

I've changed it to the Twilio appropriate "To", "From", and "Body" parts.  I get back a "400 Bad Request", "code 21604 A 'To' phone number is required".

I am providing a "To", so clearly it's just not understanding my json packet.
Can anyone fill me in on exactly what Twilio request packet should look like?

Comment: You just forgot the most important: **your code**

Comment: The code is a vary large program, with this particular routine patched in and out with if/then so it can still work with plivo if I choose to abandon twilio, so I didn't include it.  Also, I'm asking for the packet format, not code analysis.  But you're absolutely right, I should pull out the relevant part to a small test app and include that.  I'll get back to it.  (BTW: thanks for the super-fast reply!)

Comment: I've shrunk it down as much as I can, but I can't get it to fit into this comment window.  (Sorry, I'm new at posting in StackOverflow.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A 30 second search on https://metacpan.org gives me this useful result](https://metacpan.org/pod/SMS::Send::Twilio):

Install proper modules:

```
cpan SMS::Send SMS::Send::Twilio
```

Then:

```
use SMS::Send;
# Create an object. There are three required values:
my $sender = SMS::Send->new('Twilio',
  _accountsid => 'ACb657bdcb16f06893fd127e099c070eca',
  _authtoken  => 'b857f7afe254fa86c689648447e04cff',
  _from       => '+15005550006',
);
 
# Send a message to me
my $sent = $sender->send_sms(
  text => 'Messages can be up to 1600 characters',
  to   => '+31645742418',
);
 
# Did it send?
if ( $sent ) {
  print "Sent test message\n";
} else {
  print "Test message failed\n";
}
```

If you want to craft this request without a module, you can use `HTTP::Proxy` to intercept the request maybe. Should also be feasible with a `POST` with `WWW::Mechanize` or `LWP`.

With shell `cURL`:

```
curl \
    -d "Body=test" \
    -d "From=+1123456789" \
    -d "To=+1123456788" \
    -u "$twilio_account_sid:$twilio_auth_token" \
    "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/$twilio_account_sid/Messages"
```

Comment: I did not know about the SMS::Send module...  That does it just fine - thank you!  FYI for those who follow, you may need to do a 'cpan install SMS::Send' and a 'cpan install SMS::Send::Twilio'.

Comment: The Perl code above does not work for me.  The script says the message is sent, but I never receive the test text message on my phone.